# Possible false-positive - clang static analyzer and regex

Tags: c++, regex, clang, clang-static-analyzer

A colleague sees a strange warning by clang static analyzer (actually from clang-check).

This code:

```
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::regex_match("jee", std::regex("lol"));
    return 0;
}
```

produces analyzer warning:

> /usr/local/clang+llvm-3.9.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/../include/c++/v1/regex:5724:17:
> warning: Called C++ object pointer is null
> s._*node*->__exec_split(true, s);
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 warning generated.

What is going on here?

Comment: Seeing the same issue, unable to find a fix right now, other than masking it out with `#ifndef __clang_analyzer__`. I'm seeing this on Xcode 8.3 (8E162)

Comment: I am also seeing this with a call to regex_search() https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0341288f623b6252df8534fd1bdc8d3f